# Jquery .each method

Tags: php, jquery, each

learning Jquery and integrating with PHP - getting there, but have one last challenge in some code I'm working on.

I have HTML in a string, trying to pull html in  tags, might be multiple  elements in the HTML string, so trying to use each.  My function worked fine without each, below is my each integration (returns nothing currently):

```
<?php 
   $info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li><li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test2.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text too</a></strong></li>';
   $info = json_encode($info);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a", $( < ? php echo $info; ? > )).each(

    function () {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
};
```

This code below does work, but only returns the first element in the HTML:

```
<?php
   $info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>';
   $info = json_encode($info);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var output = $("a", $( < ? php echo $info; ? > )).html();
    var link = $("a", $( < ? php echo $info; ? > )).attr("href");
    alert(output);
    alert(link);
});
</script>
```

Comment: you only have one a tag that is why

Comment: Actually above code returns no alerts at all, not even the first tag. I noticed my HTML didn't have the second <a> in there (was from an example posted earlier) so added to my code and post, no dice still.

Comment: do you want to read `href` value?

Comment: ultimately i will probably use the href, but right now, i just want my each code to work, then i can filter

Comment: the 2nd example with href attr works, but doesn't get all the elements in the $info var, just the first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a description and a working example of How to use `.each()` [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

You can try this one as a example

```
$("a").each(function(index){alert($(this).html()});
```

Comment: Thanks - yea, I have been working with that specifically, including some other examples.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...sorry to be posting such a basic question, really new to jquery (last couple of days)

Comment: @user760305:you can try this one `$("a").each(function(index){alert($(this).html()});`

Comment: Thomas - using your above example, i did get to work. just looked and i was missing some }); after implementing your example, thus the original fail.  fixed, and works great now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because there are a few syntax issues.

First, change

```
< ? php echo $info; ? >
```

to

```
<?php echo $info; ?>
```

PHP doesn't like spaces and the opening and closing tags **must** appear without spaces.

Second, close the ready function and the script tag properly. Instead of

```
};
```

use,

```
});
</script>
```

Why are you encoding a piece of XML with JSON? That makes like no sense at all. Both are ways to encode data. HTML is XML too, btw. You can directly reference the `$info` variable since PHP will process everything first on the server.

```
<?php 
   $info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a", $("<?php echo $info; ?>")).each(
        function () {
            alert($(this).html());
        }
    );
});
```

Or just remove the temporary variable altogether. Makes it combersome to read, but that's essentially what PHP is doing.

```
$("a", $("<?php echo '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>'; ?>")).each(
```

Or to make it even simpler, since you already have the HTML, simply include it as part of the page and maybe give it an ID to make referencing it easier with jQuery.

```
<li id="myList">
    <strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a", "#myList").each(function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
</script>
```

This last example gets rid of PHP completely, but you weren't really using it anyways.

Comment: It wasn't rendering the HTML correctly without the JSON, the " were getting in the way and not rendering the javascript correctly...

Comment: again, definitely new to this, so i am open to suggestions.  remove the json encoding you think?  thing is I have a routine that populates the $info variable, so easier to use the var

Comment: I see, what about adding the HTML to the page directly as in my last example?

Comment: Instead of adding the entire HTML as a PHP string variable, a slightly better approach is to add the HTML directly, and only use PHP for the non-HTML parts. I've created a simple example here - http://pastium.com/view/ba2f23bbe3a0da254d68f9f72f1194d6

Comment: FYI, entire page is PHP, this is only a snippet and only jquery on the page, that's why PHP is there

Comment: first - thank u for helping - but i am afraid i am not sure how to implement your suggestion...the $info is created on the fly, there's a huge loop that runs, this code is inside it, $info changes each time...

Comment: but also i don't want the HTML to show, just want to grab the contents of the <a> tag

Comment: Inside a PHP file, it's possible to dip in and out of PHP and HTML code. See the updated code I've pasted [here](http://pastium.com/view/ba2f23bbe3a0da254d68f9f72f1194d6), and specifically see the beginning and ending of the `foreach` call, and the content between it.

Comment: right, i can dip in and out for sure, but again, in your example the HTML shows on the page - i don't want it to show, just need to grab the contents of <a> tag.

Comment: You could set the CSS `display` property of the outermost HTML tag as `none` as `<p style="display: none">..</p>` That will completely hide the HTML including any space that it would have occupied. The HTML's going to be present in the source, just not displayed to the user. Even in your example, the HTML is actually present in the source if anyone were to look at it.

Comment: ok, but i guess i'm trying to debug my .each code - my second example uses the php $info var just fine...but you think the fact i'm using the php var is my problem with the each code?

Comment: no, in my example the HTML is in a PHP variable, grabbed using CURL on another page on my site actually...

Comment: thanks for taking some time to try and help me though - sorry i am such a novice